# return decltype(auto) in static method, Gets error(vs2017) but works into(vs2012)

Tags: c++, c++14, auto, decltype

```
static decltype(auto) Get(XML_Serializer& arcSer)
{
    return TDataConverter<TDataConverterAttribute>::Get(arcSer, DT_TypeDescriptor::Instance().GetAttribute<TVal, DT_DataConverterAttribute>());
};

typedef typename DT_TypeManipulation::RemoveReference<decltype(Get(*reinterpret_cast<XML_Serializer*>(NULL)))>::Result  Type;
```

is not working into C++14(visual stdio 2017/C++17)

> error C3779: 'XML_TDataConverterProvider::Get': a function that returns 'decltype(auto)' cannot be used before it is defined

```
template<class TVal>
class XML_TDataConverterProvider
{
   private:
        template<class TDataConverterAttribute>
        struct TDataConverter
        {
            static auto Get(XML_Serializer& arcSer, TDataConverterAttribute apcDataConverterAttribute)
            -> decltype(apcDataConverterAttribute->GetDataConverter())
            {
                ASSERT(apcDataConverterAttribute);
                return apcDataConverterAttribute->GetDataConverter();
            }
        };

        template<>
        struct TDataConverter<DT_DataConverterAttribute const* const>
        {
            static DT_DataConverter& Get(XML_Serializer& arcSer, DT_DataConverterAttribute const* const apcDataConverterAttribute)

            {
                ASSERT(!apcDataConverterAttribute);
                if (apcDataConverterAttribute) {}
                return arcSer.mcConv;
            }
        };
        typedef decltype(DT_TypeDescriptor::Instance().GetAttribute<TVal, DT_DataConverterAttribute>()) TDataConverterAttribute;

    public:
        static auto Get(XML_Serializer& arcSer)
        -> decltype(TDataConverter<TDataConverterAttribute>::Get(arcSer, DT_TypeDescriptor::Instance().GetAttribute<TVal, DT_DataConverterAttribute>()))
        {
            return TDataConverter<TDataConverterAttribute>::Get(arcSer, DT_TypeDescriptor::Instance().GetAttribute<TVal, DT_DataConverterAttribute>());
        };


        typedef typename DT_TypeManipulation::RemoveReference<decltype(Get(*reinterpret_cast<XML_Serializer*>(NULL)))>::Result  Type;

};
```

and that is working into Visual Studio 2012/C++11

What is the changes to do in C++11 code to run this code?

Comment: Note that MSVS2012 is not, and doesn't purport to be, a C++11 compiler.

Comment: There is no question in your post.

Comment: Side note: instead of `*reinterpret_cast<XML_Serializer*>(NULL)` rather use `std::declval<XML_Serializer>()` which is designed just for this purpose.

Comment: OK, Thanks but my issue is related C++14 changes

Comment: @PawanKumar: A similar bug has been reported and fixed. See this link: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/324077/158-regression-a-function-that-returns-auto-cannot.html.

Comment: I have latest build 15.9.4 but still I get the error,  I think its different one.